# Symfony2 path function right url

Tags: symfony, path, urldecode

When I use the path function in Twig, there is a strange problem with the '?' when I want to set GET parameter.

Example:

```
href="{{ path(brData.router, {(brData.slug): brData.url}) }}"
```

If I set now as brData.url: 'search?q=bla',

then twig is coding the url in this way:

domain.com/search%3Fq=bla , and the search can not be executed. How can I prepare the url in the righ form: domain.com/search?q=bla

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 0):

The use of `domain.com/search?q=bla` involves you have a route defined with the path `/search`.

If you have the route, just pass a parameter and its value without wrapping it in a `?key=[value]`.

Example assuming `search_route` is the name of your `/search` route:

```
{% set fieldValue = 'bla' %}
{% set url = path('search_route', {'q': fieldValue}) %}
```

So `href="{{ url }}"` will give `href="domain.com/search?q=bla"`.